# Solve $C_i$ from $\frac{A_i} {\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i)} = \frac{B_i * C_i} {\sum_{i=1}^n (B_i*C_i)} $

Tags: real-analysis

I have a dataset with n observations. Each observation $n=i$ has a **known** value of $A_i$, a **known** value of $B_i$, but also an **unknown** value of $C_i$.

The three terms are related to each other in the following manner:

$$\frac{A_i} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (A_i)} = \frac{B_i \cdot C_i} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (B_i\cdot C_i)}$$

alternatively:

$$A_i = B_i * C_i * X$$ Where X is an unknown factor that stays constant for all i.

Is there a way to express the unknown term $C_i$ for all the observations in this dataset?
If there is no algebraic way, is there a way to estimate possible values of $C$ using computation estimations (like MCMC or similar?).

I would be so grateful for any help or hint!

Andreas

Comment: I mean why don't you just choose $C_i = \frac{B_i}{A_i}$ ?

Comment: Hmm, that seems very simple, but I find it difficult to understand how you reach that conclusion.

I might misunderstand you, but do you assume that $A_i = B_i * C_i$ ?

For clarity, $A_i = B_i * C_i * X$ Where X is an unknown factor that stays constant for all i.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, yes I meant $C_i=\frac{A_i}{B_i}$, that would satisfy your condition above. Of course $C_i = x \frac{A_i}{B_i}$ also satisfies the condition for any say $x\neq0$. Maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know X. Thats why i choose to divide by the sums, in order to get X out of the equation.
So although your suggestion solves the equation, I remain unable to calculate the value of C.

Comment: I have now got to this point.

$$C_i \cdot X = \frac{A_i}{B_i} $$

$$\frac{C_i \cdot X} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n C_i \cdot X} = \frac{ \frac{A_i}{B_i}} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac {A_i} {B_i}}$$


$$\frac{C_i} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n C_i} = \frac{ \frac{A_i}{B_i}} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac {A_i} {B_i}}$$

Here, Ive got only C on one side, and no X is part of the game. So Im satisfied, even if I will only get the relative proportion of C. Please let me know if Im wrong, 

Otherwise, many thanks for your help and engagement!!

Comment: Yes, what you did is true (assuming $X\neq0$), even though as you note, you will only get $C_i$ up to multiplication by a constant. Also, note that it would be "cleaner" to use a different index for the sum than the fixed index .

Comment: Thank you Maximilian, this was truly helpful! And good point with the index, I will keep that for the future. I'm obviously not a mathematician, but an ecologist, and that's why this forum is so great :). Thanks!